# I need to know how to loop a .wav file n amount of times in java

Tags: java, loops, wav

I need to know how to loop an audio file a certain amount of times in java. I can't tell what is wrong with the code I have. if you need to see any more of the program I can post it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static double [] audioLoop(double [] audio, int loops)
    {
        double [] result = new double[audio.length*loops];
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {   
                result[i] = audio[i]*loops;                     
        }
        if (loops <= 0)
            return null;
        else
            return result;  
    }
```

Comment: I have the files. I just run them with the program through the command prompt.

Comment: Presumably the doubles contain the audio data?

Comment: With the program I have made it where I can merge, cut, pad, reverse, change volume, and echo but I am stuck on the looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
    result[i] = audio[i % audio.length];
 }
```

Comment: Do you understand how it works, like what the % does?

Comment: I kind of understand, but I'm not 100% on why you used %.

Comment: The percent gives the remainder of i/audio.length. So it will copy over the whole audio array to result, than once i gets to audio.length it will start copying from the beginning again.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much